# Fetching image from the database throws null pointer excception on getJsonArray

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to fetch image from the database and display it on my android device.
At this point of my code I am getting a nullpointer exception

```
str_login = json.getJSONArray("info");
```

This is the code before the above line of code is executed

```
String link_url = "192.168.19.8";
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        link_url = Referensi.link+"/product_api/getDataProduct.php";
        JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);
```

This is my logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ecommysql.yonandroid/com.ecommysql.yonandroid.PhotoProduk}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my oncreate method codes

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_product);

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        link_url = Referensi.link+"/product_api/getDataProduct.php";
        JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

        try {
            str_login = json.getJSONArray("info");

            for (int i = 0; i < str_login.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject ar = str_login.getJSONObject(i);

                String id    = ar.getString(YA_ID);
                String nmp   = ar.getString(YA_NAMAPRODUK);
                String stok  = ar.getString(YA_STOK);
                String harga = ar.getString(YA_HARGA);
                String des   = ar.getString(YA_DESKRIPSI);
                String img   = ar.getString(YA_IMAGE);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(YA_ID, id);
                map.put(YA_NAMAPRODUK, nmp);
                map.put(YA_STOK, stok);
                map.put(YA_HARGA, harga);
                map.put(YA_DESKRIPSI, des);
                map.put(YA_IMAGE, img);

                daftar_produk.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.adapter_listview();
    }
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Post your JSON format value as string format.

Comment: How do I get the json format.

Comment: post your logcat. also some more code.

Comment: I have done that @sourabhbans

Comment: i think here `JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);` json is null.
check your response that you are getting.

Comment: How do I check the responce